# Autocomplete widget closing due to PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

my places api is enabled .
all the things are fine just places api not working.

i have gone through many solution but not a single one helped me.

2019-03-25 17:59:20.317 8124-8223/com.snaplista.com E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 4, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#4) Application request limit reached} 2019-03-25 17:59:20.409 15228-15256/? E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist! 2019-03-25 17:59:20.410 15228-15228/? E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size! 2019-03-25 17:59:20.887 1592-1592/? E/FullInputEventModel: onStartInputView event aborted: eef: Unable to get TouchTypeExtractedText from InputConnection. (class eef) 2019-03-25 17:59:20.889 1592-1592/? E/FullInputEventModel: selectionUpdated event aborted: eef: Unable to get TouchTypeExtractedText from InputConnection. (class eef) 2019-03-25 17:59:20.906 15228-15228/? E/Places: Unknown PlaceAutocompleteAdapter state change. 2019-03-25 17:59:21.021 15228-15228/? E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length 2019-03-25 17:59:21.022 15228-15228/? E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length 2019-03-25 17:59:21.329 21564-21685/? E/Volley: [16961] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/autocompleteWidget?key=AIzaSyDCajhS3sEGJvE9GyZ-M6WNV0E7VKC20IU 2019-03-25 17:59:21.333 21564-15115/? E/Places: Places API for Android does not seem to be enabled for your app. See https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup for more details. 2019-03-25 17:59:21.336 21564-15115/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=65, operation=AutocompleteWidgetQuota OperationException[Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}] at bdng.b(:com.google.android.gms@15090021@15.0.90 (040408-231259764):1) at bdmt.a(:com.google.android.gms@15090021@15.0.90 (040408-231259764):4) at yzz.run(:com.google.android.gms@15090021@15.0.90 (040408-231259764):27) at bgah.run(:com.google.android.gms@15090021@15.0.90 (040408-231259764):2) at rrm.run(:com.google.android.gms@15090021@15.0.90 (040408-231259764):21) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) at rxo.run(Unknown Source:7) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784) 2019-03-25 17:59:21.343 15228-15228/? E/Places: Autocomplete widget closing due to PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED 2019-03-25 17:59:21.377 3337-9717/? E/[HwRecSys]HwRecSysService: getIsRportDirectService is false! 2019-03-25 17:59:21.510 1818-29863/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 103 2019-03-25 17:59:21.516 8124-8124/com.snaplista.com E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length 2019-03-25 17:59:21.516 8124-8124/com.snaplista.com E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length 2019-03-25 17:59:21.661 1104-1441/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{fa468aa u0 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.places.ui.autocomplete.AutocompleteActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true

Answer (score 0):

You should file a support case via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support as this may involve investigating your project.

Also do check if you have followed the "Migrating to the New Places SDK Client" especially the "Install the client library" part. Here's the link :

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#install_the_client_library